# What is the fastest way to check if a number is in specific range in python?

Tags: python, integer, range

I have 5 ranges:

```
1-50 ---> "range1"
51-100 ---> "range2"
101-150 ---> "range3"
151-200 ---> "range4"
201-250 ---> "range5"
```

Ranges do not overlap, each range has lower and upper bound, next range starts where the previous one ends. I decide the range lengths. they might not be equal in size.

I have a variable that shows a number, for example

```
x = 153
```

If x is between 1 and 50 then it should return "range1", if between 51 and 100 then "range2", and so on.
What is the fastest way of doing it in python, considering there may be much more than 5 ranges, and the number is large?

Comment: Are the numbers more likely to be in some known ranges than in others?

Comment: No, the number might be in any of the ranges, with equal probability.

Comment: how do you get these ranges?  are they 2 ints in an array? do they overlap? are the ranges sparse?

Comment: they do not overlap, each range has lower and upper bound, next range starts where this range ends. I decide the range lengths. they might not be in equal size.

Answer (score 2):

Because your ranges are strictly adjacent and in increasing order, you can use bisection:

```
from bisect import bisect

ranges = [1, 51, 101, 151, 201]
if 0 < x <= 250:
    print('range{}'.format(bisect(ranges, x))
else:
    print('Out of bounds')
```

Bisection takes O(logN) steps to find the matching range out of N possibilities.

Comment: this only works if the ranges butt up against eachother like that... @alwbtc is that the case?

Comment: This is faster than using a traditional `if` loop?

Comment: @karina yes, they are against each other.

Comment: @alwbtc: this is a O(logN) solution, for N ranges. A loop would take O(N).